# ABAQUS errors: File open failed (utl_File: CreateFile in OpenWrite) error: T?

Tags: matlab, macros, abaqus

I'm trying to loop an ABAQUS macros in MATLAB. The last bit of the macros is save the CAE file, submit the INP file. I'm using 'system' command in MATLAB to loop this macros.

In MATLAB, the ABAQUS analysis job is completed, but then the following error happened:

Abaqus JOB L2H1_dynamics COMPLETED 
*** Error: File open failed (utl_File: CreateFile in OpenWrite) 
error: T 
file: C:\Temp\L2H1_dynamics.cae

Abaqus Error: cae exited with an error.

ans =

1

What is OpenWrite? What does error: T mean?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have write permission and enough space on "C:\temp"? Otherwise with no code examples there isn't much here to go on.  As a bit of an aside abaqus python scripting is plenty powerful. Unless you really really need matlab functionality I would advise letting abaqus/cae/python do the main looping.

Comment: Hi agentp, I do have permission and enough space on this location. I'll paste the code here if possible. I'm doing this because I need to link MATLAB with ABAQUS.

Answer (score 0):

The last bit of the code looks like this:

```
session.writeXYReport(fileName='abaqus.rpt', xyData=(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, 
    x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20))
mdb.saveAs(pathName='C:/Temp/L2H1_dynamics')
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=a)
mdb.JobFromInputFile(name='L2H1_dynamics', 
    inputFileName='C:\\Temp\\L2H1_dynamics.inp', type=ANALYSIS, 
    atTime=None, waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90, 
    memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE, getMemoryFromAnalysis=True, 
    explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE, 
    userSubroutine='', scratch='', parallelizationMethodExplicit=DOMAIN, 
    numDomains=1, activateLoadBalancing=False, multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, 
    numCpus=1)
mdb.jobs['L2H1_dynamics'].submit(consistencyChecking=OFF)
```

I believe error happened because of this bit.

Comment: you should edit your question with this info, not post it as an answer. Anyway another possible reason would be that the file with that name is already open. You can use ordinary python tools for debugging here, `import os; os.path` , `os.access` etc.

Comment: also unrelated to the error, but you know `saveas` does not create the inp file, it only saves the cae file. Hopefully you also have `mdb.writeInput()` someplace..

Answer (score 0):

Filenames should be written with the double slash, as you did for your input file name.

```
>>> mdb.saveAs(pathName='C:\\temp\\test.cae')
The model database has been saved to "C:\temp\test.cae".
```

Can you run the py script outside matlab so that you can isolate the problem. i.e. using "run script" in abaqus when CAE is already open.